# View PDF from Server on Client Machine C# Web Application ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, iis-8, intranet

I created a virtual directory on the IIS server (window server 2012)
that let me access all the pdf file in a particular folder which the client would need to access
[image]

Then I wrote a method that after the user click on a link in the grid view
[image]

The code I wrote is below:
[image]

[image]

After publishing my C# web application to server than accessing the web application on a client machine, I click on the completed link hoping that it would download to client machine but instead it downloads to server machine
[image]

Please help me download/ open file on virtual folder or c drive to client machine.

I also put the downloaded pdf file in the following path and set the folder to shared:
[image]

Comment: is that mvc or plain asp.net app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be helpful for you to download a pdf at client's side:

```
string filepath = @"C:\yourfile.pdf";
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            System.IO.Stream stream = null;
            try
            {
                // Open the file into a stream. 
                stream = new FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
                // Total bytes to read: 
                long bytesToRead = stream.Length;
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                // Read the bytes from the stream in small portions. 
                while (bytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    // Make sure the client is still connected. 
                    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        // Read the data into the buffer and write into the 
                        // output stream. 
                        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
                        int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        Response.Flush();
                        // We have already read some bytes.. need to read 
                        // only the remaining. 
                        bytesToRead = bytesToRead - length;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Get out of the loop, if user is not connected anymore.. 
                        bytesToRead = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
                // An error occurred.. 

            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I get an errorLog Type: ERROR

Execution Time: 18-Apr-2016 14:17:45.266

Source: Save To Client Machine

Message: Could not find file 'C:\PCR-20160214-0001-1.pdf'. As you can see from the image above, I have that pdf file in c:/  . I made your solution to a method called SaveToClientMachine

Comment: You should put your file in a Shareable location(i.e, **inetpub**) and make sure that your application has required **privilege** for accessing the file

Comment: I did what you said, please refer to the last image in my question.  However, this time, I don't receive any error message and yet no pdf appears.

Comment: To check if it's a matter of privileges, you can try to add **everyone** account to your folder (where pdfs exist).